# copy and paste dynamic effect in graph editor

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I'm animating scaling an object.
Id' like to add a dynamic effect to the end of the scale, i.e. a bounce.
I am able to box select the key of the X, Y and Z channels and add a dynamic effect to all three in the Graph Editor.
But when it comes to editing the bounce I cannot find an easy way to manipulate the bounce of all three channels simultaneously.
Then I hoped to be able to copy the dynamic effect from one channel to the other two. No luck there either.
Am I overlooking something obvious or is there just no easy way to sync a dynamic effect across several channels?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding two keyframes. One at frame `0` and the other where you want it to stop scaling.

When you've done that, click on the first marker and press <kbd>T</kbd> and change the interpolation to *bounce*.

Comment: Thanks.
Yes I am aware of that.
My question was how to apply the bounce to X, Y and Z simultaneously and more importantly edit the bounce of all three channels simultaneously.